# Displaying X/Y data in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, convert, latitude-longitude

I am very new to GIS. I am unfamiliar with the terms so I may not have found similar queries.

I just want to display my XY data on a layer. However, whenever I import my CSV/XLS file to ArcMap, the longitude and latitude variables do not show up.
Is this because the coordinates are in a different format?

In what format my data and how can I convert them to decimal degrees?

[image]

Comment: You need to convert your data into decimal degrees to be able to plot them. Explore the [Convert coordinate notation tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-coordinate-notation.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Your longitude and latitude columns are seen as Text fields due to to presence of non-numeral characters (°, E and N). First find a way to remove those characters probably in Excel before importing into ArcMap.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll follow your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Only the number should remain, and the column should be in number format, not text. The characters after the number should be deleted, and there are some where there is a space before the number, and the blank line should be deleted. ArcMap can only read .xls format, not .xlsx, so it should be saved in an earlier 97-2003 workbook. Make xy event layer will already be able to read it and make it into a point layer.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for you help!